# Transaction in Room android

Tags: android, database

how I can insert data to multiple tables in a single transaction. In android docs, @Transaction annotation is used and call two methods in a single transaction but these methods are in the same interface. My question is how to call methods of multiple interfaces in a single transaction thank you

Comment: see `android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase`

Comment: As per my understanding, @ Transaction ony can be added on method in @ Dao class. If you want the therefore, you can only declare a @ Query to create a custom query on another table, add create another @ Transaction method calling methods accessing 2 tables.

Comment: If you want each @Dao class only contains script method on 1 table only. Then, you cannot use @ Transaction, you may use runInTransaction to run 2 methods in 2 Daos.